# Spacing is different on appended elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add a new row to a table with two select boxes dynamically after the last row has been altered.  It is all functioning except the spacing is different on the appended rows.  The initial row at page load has approximately 2-3 pixels of spacing, which is good.  The appended rows have absoultely 0 spacing between the two select boxes and actually overlap slightly.  I have tried messing with padding and margin values but those 2-3 always seem to differ between the first row and the dynamically added rows.

```
field_td.append(s);
field_td.append(set);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your static HTML has white space (like newlines) between the tags. If you want to mimic this behaviour in the dynamic part then do:

```
field_td.append(' ', s, ' ', set);
```

Comment: Perfect, it works.  Thanks.  I read something similar in other threads but it was mostly related to the <p> tag so I wasn't sure if the concept of newlines applied the same here.